# Print successes with redex-check

Tags: racket, plt-redex

I am using redex-check to validate a model against another, and would like to see the intermediate (successful) results for debugging purposes. The most obvious way to do this would be to have the property-expr print the given term as a side-effect, but this is inelegant. Is there another way to look at intermediate redex-check attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the right idea on how to do this. In fact, the [example for `redex-check` in the docs actually does this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/redex/The_Redex_Reference.html?q=redex-check#%28form._%28%28lib._redex%2Freduction-semantics..rkt%29._redex-check%29%29):

```
(let ([R (reduction-relation
            empty-lang
            (--> (Σ) 0)
            (--> (Σ number) number)
            (--> (Σ number_1 number_2 number_3 ...)
                 (Σ ,(+ (term number_1) (term number_2))
                    number_3 ...)))])
    (redex-check
     empty-lang
     (Σ number ...)
     (printf "~s\n" (term (number ...)))
      #:attempts 3
      #:source R))
```

Writes the following result to `current-output-port`:

```
()
(0)
(2 0)
redex-check: no counterexamples in 1 attempt (with each clause)
```